# htaccess Redirect all pages except some not working

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all pages on my website to the homepage, except a few. I found some solutions on stackoverflow but none of these are working so I assume there might be conflicts with the rest of my htaccess which I didn't write by myself.

```
RewriteEngine on
# begin my code
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/agb$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/impressum$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/datenschutzerklaerung$
RewriteRule .* https://www.mywebsite.com [R=301,L]
# end my code
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

I have tried to write RewriteRule .* / [R=301,L]

and I've also tried to put my code beneath the rest, but this results in a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(agb|impressum|datenschutzerklaerung|)$
RewriteRule .* https://www.mywebsite.com [R=301,L]
```

Try in a new browser in incognito mode.

Comment: @Insane sorry, try it again please.

Comment: This works! Now I have the problem that css, js, and img sources don't get loaded. Can I somehow exclude them by file type or do I have to exclude them one by one?

Comment: Ah unfortunately agb, impressum and datenschutzerklaerung aren't accessable anymore. Figured out I can exclude ressource file paths like this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/